Store data from a form in a state before sending
I am creating a simple chat application using Remix. User shall enter a message and when clicking a submit button, the message is sent to the backend that creates a reply. Sending the message to the server works fine, but how can I locally save a copy of the message to display it in a chat history? Or in other words: how to access the form values on sending the form while still letting Remix do its job?
This is my code to send the chat message to the server:
// server side function
export async function action({
  request,
}: ActionFunctionArgs) {
  const formData = await request.formData();
  const chatMessage = formData.get("chatMessage");

  // generate chat reply on server side, no issue here
}

// client side code
<fetcher.Form method="post">
      <input
        type="text"
        name="chatMessage"
        placeholder="Enter your message"
      />
      <button type="submit">
        Send
      </button>
</fetcher.Form>

// TODO: keep a history of sent messages on the client


You can do it entirely client-side with a combination of useFetcher, useState, and useEffect, like this:
import { useFetcher } from '@remix-run/react'
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

/* ... */

export default function ChatRoute() {
  const fetcher = useFetcher()
  const [sentMessages, setSentMessages] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    if (fetcher.state === 'submitting') {
      const chatMessage = fetcher.formData.get('chatMessage')
      setSentMessages([...sentMessages, chatMessage])
    }
  }, [fetcher.state])

  return (
    <>
      {/* ... */}
      <fetcher.Form method="post">
        <input
          type="text"
          name="chatMessage"
          placeholder="Enter your message"
        />
        <button type="submit">Send</button>
      </fetcher.Form>
      {/* ... */}
    </>
  )
}

